# compass doesn't find singularitygs

Tags: rubygems, gruntjs, compass-sass, singularitygs

The compass framework can't load/find the 'singularitygs' framework/extension:

I installed the packages via RubyGem:

```
gem list compass && gem list singularity && gem list breakpoint
```

Which gives me the following information:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

compass (1.0.0.alpha.18)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.17)
compass-import-once (1.0.2)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

singularitygs (1.1.2)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

breakpoint (2.4.1)
```

The task `compass:dev` of my Gruntfile:

```
compass:
  dev:
    options:
      trace: true
      require: ['singularitygs']
      sassDir: '<%= dir.sass %>'
      cssDir: '<%= dir.css %>'
      environment: 'development'
```

The result:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
LoadError on line 51 of /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: no such file to load -- singularitygs
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Next I tried a `config.rb` file:

```
compass:
  dev:
    options:
      trace: true
      config: 'config.rb'
      sassDir: '<%= dir.sass %>'
      cssDir: '<%= dir.css %>'
      environment: 'development'
```

With the following content:

```
require 'singularitygs'
```

That's all, and here is the result:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
LoadError on line 51 of /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: no such file to load -- singularitygs
  /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in `require'
  config.rb:1:in `get_binding'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:20:in `get_binding'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:23:in `parse_string'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `_parse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `new_from_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:204:in `with_defaults'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:42:in `configuration_for'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:97:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:37:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44
  /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/compass:23
Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

So, I checked, if Compass has that framework `compass frameworks --trace` in another directory:

```
Available Frameworks & Patterns:

  * blueprint
    - blueprint/basic      - A basic blueprint install that mimics the actual blueprint css.
    - blueprint/buttons    - Button Plugin
    - blueprint/link_icons - Icons for common types of links
    - blueprint/project    - The blueprint framework.
    - blueprint/semantic   - The blueprint framework for use with semantic markup.
  * compass
    - compass/ellipsis     - Plugin for cross-browser ellipsis truncated text.
    - compass/extension    - Generate a compass extension.
    - compass/pie          - Integration with http://css3pie.com/
    - compass/project      - The default project layout.
```

If I execute the same command `compass frameworks --trace` in the root directory, where the `config.rb` file is located, I will get the same error:

```
LoadError on line 51 of /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: no such file to load -- singularitygs
  /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in `require'
  /Users/darius/Code/www/voidplus.de/www/config.rb:1:in `get_binding'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:20:in `get_binding'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:23:in `parse_string'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `_parse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `new_from_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:204:in `with_defaults'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:42:in `configuration_for'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:97:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/list_frameworks.rb:7:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44
  /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/compass:23
```

I don't know, what I could try to solve that problem. In addition I uninstall and install all gem files without success. Maybe it's the wrong gem environment `gem env`?

```
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin
```

Thanks for any help and hints,
Darius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade Ruby from `2.0.0` to `1.9.3` via `rbenv` and that solves the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Singularity 1.1.2 is not compatible with Compass 1.0.0. We have a pre-release version of Singularity 1.2.0 that is, though.

Gem compatibility issues is exactly why we [recommend using Bundler](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Installation#wiki-installation) to manage gem versions. If you would like to use Singularity with Compass 1.0.0, do the following:

1. `(sudo) gem install bundler`
2. Create a file, `Gemfile`, at the root of your project and add the following:

   ```
   source 'http://rubygems.org'
   gem 'singularitygs', '~>1.2.0.rc.6'
   ```
3. Run `bundle install --path vendor`
4. Ignore `vendor` directory in your Version Control system (if using Git, add `./vendor` to your `.gitignore` file)
5. Add `bundleExec: true` to your `compass:dev`
   Grunt task

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I tried that and get the following error: `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in block in materialize: Could not find chunky_png-1.3.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`. I don't know, why `grunt-contrib-compass` with `bundleExec` doens't find the local installed gems by bundler. There is a `.bundle/config` with the content `BUNDLE_PATH: vendor`. The gems were in `./vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/`.

Comment: Did `bundle install` fail?

Comment: No, that works fine. I ran the same commands to check differences, now `gem list compass` puts `compass (0.12.2), compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.17), compass-import-once (1.0.2)`. It's a bit curious.

Comment: `gem list` won't help. Your `Gemfile.lock` will list the available gems Bundler will work with.

Comment: Okay, that looks fine `singularitygs (1.2.0.rc.6), breakpoint (~> 2.4), compass (~> 1.0.0.alpha.13), sass (~> 3.3.0.rc.2)`. `compass (1.0.0.alpha.18)` requires `chunky_png (~> 1.2)`, but grunt doesn't find it locally.

Comment: Did you save your Gruntfile.js? Is chunky_png  in your vendor file? Is the Gemfile and .bundle/config at the same root at Gruntfile?

Comment: Yes, I saved it. Yes, bundler generated `ruby/1.9.1/gems/breakpoint-2.4.1/` (with content)  in `./vendor`. Yes, `./Gemfile`, `./Gruntfile.coffee` and `./bundle/config`.

Comment: I will try another ruby versions. I guess that there are troubles with the version of ruby with specific gems.

Comment: Good news, I downgrade Ruby from `2.0.0` to `1.9.3` via `rbenv` and it works. Nevertheless thanks for your help and time. Happy coding, Darius